# Strange Behaviour of <f:event>

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, httplistener

i'm using PrimeFaces 5, Glassfish server ver.4 and firefox as browser. I'm developing a web app via Netbeans8.0.1 where in index.xhtml page I need to show a list of tips at each login.
To do this i'm using this code in my index.xhtml page

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{promemoriaController.promemoriaInScadenza()}"/>
```

This "f:event" is outside the "f:metadata> tag. 
I don't know why but the f:event listner is executed twice at every login.
I'm sure that the usage of the promemoriaController.promemoriaInScadenza() is only in the f:event>.
Thank's a lot for your replies

Comment: can you provide the path of it's parent elements, from <html> to <f:event> ?

Comment: also, do you have any components with autoUpdate="true"? or any event that reloads the whole @Form

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1. How can i find the path from <html> to <f:event> while running ? For element with autoupdate="true" i'haven't find nothing.

Comment: Ok i have found <p:growl > with autoupdate="true". After delete it all works well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the container of this `<f:event>`element, is rendered 2 times. 1 from the initial page load, and another one, probably from some ajax action

You could check all the parent elements of this , and see if any of these is called to update from another action. Using the `autoupdate="true"` attribute can also trigger some unexpected updates and re-renderings

Answer (score -1):

Check if your `<f:event/>` tag is inside `<f:metadata>` - if so, put it outside.

Comment: Is outside. It is inside the <h:body>.